# Complex numbers: find all $z$ such that $e^{z-2}=-ie^2$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Ok, so I think I'm getting the hang of this. Is this more or less on the right track?

$$e^{z-2}=-ie^2$$
$$e^ze^{-2}=-ie^2$$
$$e^z=-ie^4$$
$$\ln(e^z)=\ln(-ie^4)$$
$$z=\ln|-i|+iarg(-i)+2\pi ik+4$$
$$z=\frac{i\pi}{2}-\frac{i\pi}{2}+4+2\pi ik$$
$$z=4+2\pi ik$$

Comment: There is $i$ missing!  It should be $z=i\pi +4+ i2\pi k$.

Comment: Yes, $i$ is missing. Otherwise correct. You can imagine it in complex plane. When you have the equation:
$$e^z=-ie^4$$
you know, that the angle of the rhs is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, which corresponds to $e^{3i\pi/2}$. In other words, instead of using the complex logarithm, you could rewrite the equation as
$$e^z=e^{3i\pi/2}e^4=e^{3i\pi/2+4}$$

Comment: You missed it when you derived $ \ln(-i) $.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal yup, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e^{z-2}=-ie^2=e^{2-\frac{i \pi}{2}+2\pi ki}$, so $$z-2=2-\frac{i \pi}{2}+2\pi ki$$
$$z=4+i(2\pi k-\frac{ \pi}{2}).$$
In your solution the last two rows are seems to be wrong, since $arg(-i)=-\pi/2$.

Comment: How did you get $e^{2-\frac{i\pi}{2}+2\pi ki}$ ?

Comment: Just expressed $-i$ in exponential form

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from line 4:
$$
z=ln\left(i^3\right)+4........(i)
$$
We know,
$ln(z)=ln(r)+i(Arg(z)+2k\pi)$ where k=0,+-1,+-2....

Applying this to $ln\left(-i\right)$, we get:

$$ln\left(-i\right)=ln(1)+i(-\pi/2 +2k\pi)=i(-\pi/2 +2k\pi)$$
Putting this value back in equation (i):
$$z=4+i(-\pi/2 +2k\pi)$$